# Installing rjags packages on windows

Tags: r, jags

While installing Jags 4.0 and `rjags` package in R, it seems there is a problem in matching library between Jags4.0 and "rjags" packages. 
I first installed Jags 4.0 into "C:\Program Files\JAGS\JAGS-4.0.0" and then I tried to install rjags packages with R

```
install.packages("rjags")
```

My default package library is : "C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Documents\R\win-library\3.2"

When I tried to install `rjags`, R shows below, and I cannot load installed rjags into my R.

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/AA/Desktop/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

How should I solve this problem?

Edit to reflect the comments:
Loading library `library(rjags)` results in the following error:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details: call:
>   fun(libname, pkgname) error: Failed to locate any version of JAGS
>   version 3 The rjags package is just an interface to the JAGS library
>   Make sure you have installed JAGS-3.0.0.exe or higher from
>   sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files Error: package or namespace
>   load failed for ‘rjags’

Comment: I'm not sure you have a problem.  Have you tried `library(rjags)` or tried to run any analyses yet?

Comment: Yes. When I did. it shows error like this

Comment: Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Failed to locate any version of JAGS version 3

The rjags package is just an interface to the JAGS library
Make sure you have installed JAGS-3.0.0.exe or higher from
http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’

Comment: I solved it. The problem was the version of JAGS. By installing JAGS 3.4.0, the issue was solved.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I was just looking into that.  While JAGS 4.0.0 is available, the CRAN `rjags` hasn't yet been updated (https://martynplummer.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/jags-4-0-0-is-released/).  When the CRAN version is updated at some unspecified date in the future it will work again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference in case someone is looking for the same issue, I collected the comments made by @Benjamin and @BoramLim in an answer.

#### Summary:

There is a version difference between the jags installer (version 4.0) and rjags on cran which for now depends on jags version 3.x. You can find a working version of rjags on Sourceforge.

Release notes from [blog](https://martynplummer.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/jags-4-0-0-is-released/)

> After a long gestation period, JAGS 4.0.0 was finally released last
> week. If you go to the [project page on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/) then you should see
> an appropriate download link for your platform (binary packages for
> Windows and Mac OS X; source tarball for other platforms). Binary
> packages are also available for some Linux distributions. See the [JAGS
> homepage](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/) for details.
>
> Mac users should note that you need OS X 10.9 or later (i.e.
> Mavericks, Yosemite, or El Capitan). Older releases are no longer
> supported.
>
> The rjags package for R has been updated to work with the new release
> of JAGS. It is not yet uploaded to CRAN, and the version of rjags that
> is available on CRAN (rjags_3-15) does not work with JAGS 4.0.0.
> However, you can [download rjags_4-3 from Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/rjags/4/). Again, binary
> packages are available for Windows (.zip) and Mac OS X (.tgz).

Comment: I just looked on CRAN and `rjags` was updated today (Oct 22), so you may expect that `rjags` will run with JAGS 4.0.0 (full disclosure, I haven't tried yet).

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/JAGS/4.x/Windows/