# Unable to load rjags on windows 10

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I'm having trouble loading `rjags`. Operating system is Windows 10. R version is 4.1.1, and JAGS is 4.3.0. And `rjags` is installed through `install.packages("rjags")` Below is what happened when I tried to load `rjags`.

```
require(rjags)
Loading required package: rjags
Loading required package: coda
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:  .onLoad failed
in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:   call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: Failed to locate any version of JAGS version 4

The rjags package is just an interface to the JAGS library
Make sure you have installed JAGS-4.x.y.exe (for any x >=0, y>=0) from
http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files
```

The same error message also appeared when I tried JAGS 3.4.0, 4.1.0, and 4.2.0.

I saw on a different post that previously, people solved a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268990/installing-rjags-packages-on-windows) by using an older version of JAGS. That solution didn't work, sadly. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found a solution on the JAGS website: I ran

```r
Sys.setenv(JAGS_HOME="C:/Program Files/JAGS/JAGS-4.3.0")
```

at the RStudio console prompt and this seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: I just found another solution yesterday. When JAGS is being installed, it asks whether to install it for all users of the PC or one user. `rjags` can't be loaded if JAGS is installed for all users, but it can if it's installed just for one user. So I guess the issue is with the default way for `rjags` locate JAGS in the system.

Comment: Thanks, @EricAtani. Your solution is better, as the one I shared only works for the current session.

Comment: @EricAtani where do you see this setting in the Jags installation? I'm having the same issue with Jags not working when I install JAGS-4.2.0-Rtools33.exe on my Windows 10 machine. I don't see any way to change how the program is shared when I do the installation.